# Android Floating Action Bar hidden below bottombar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The main screens xml of my app looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom|end" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/menu_bottombar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_showShadow="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

which translates to a ui like this:

[image: app ui]

As you can see, the fab is hidden behind the bottombar.
I tried using different layout anchor attributes and margins inside the fab element but I cant get it to be above the bottombar.
I should mention that I'm using the roughike bottombar library.
Any ideas on how I could make it work?

Comment: Add "android:layout_above"@+id/bottomBar" in android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_showShadow="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/menu_bottombar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also see this issue:https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/442

Hope it helps

Comment: @AlexGogl if the answer helped..mark it as correct..thankx